# How to encrypt password using pbkdf2_sha256 algorithm in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, keycloak

I am using angular 6 and keycloak, I don't want to send password in clear text over the network.

Keycloak supports only pbkdf2_sha256 hashing algoritm, so I need a suggestion on how I can encrypt a password using same hashing algorithm before sending it to keycloak over the network

Comment: If you're using HTTPS and you're not passing the password in the URL, it's no longer being sent over in plain text. Hashing passwords on the client-side is usually  [not a good practice](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/https-security-should-password-be-hashed-server-side-or-client-side).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any NPM package for hashing password at the client-side, (sha1, sha256),
As long as you are not storing the password on the client side as plain text avoid doing this:

```
npm install sha1
import * as sha1 from 'sha1/sha1';
const encryptedPassword = sha1(userCreds.password);
```

Instead, you can useJsonWebToken and HTTPS, Hope this helps